# Product of two closed sets in product space

Tags: general-topology

I already know that if $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in Y then $U \times V$ is open in the product space $X \times Y$. I wonder if it was also true that "if $U$ is closed in $X$ and $V$ is closed in $Y$ then $U\times V$ is closed in $X \times Y$"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think it out.  What is the complement of $U\times V$?

It is $\{(u,v)|$ where it is not true that both $ u\in U$ and $v \in V\} =\{(u,v)| u\not\in U$ or $v\not \in V\}=\{u \in U^c$ or $v\in V^c\} =$

$U^c\times Y \cup X\times V^c$.  As $Y, X$ are open then $U^c\times Y$ is open and $X\times V^c$ is open.

So $(U\times V)^c$ is open.  So $U\times V$ is closed.

Comment: If $W$ is a set in $X \times Y$, can I write $W=U\times V$ with $U$ and $V$ is an abitrary set in $X$ and $Y$ respectively ?

Comment: If you have *any* two sets $A$ and $B$ then the notation $A\times B$ is used to denote the set of ordered pairs $\{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$.  So if $A=\{red,yellow, green\} $and $B=\{babar, tantor\}$ then $A\times B = \{(red,babar),(red, tantor), (yellow, babar),(yellow, tantor),(green, babar),(green, tantor)\}$.  So... yes, of course you can.

Comment: Thank you, your example is so vivid :)